# exclude files with specific starting characters bash using regex

Tags: regex, bash

`"/home/shell/DELETE-ME-*"` which *includes* all the files that starts with DELETE-ME- in shell directory.

In the same fashion, would like to *excludes* all the files that starts with DELETE-ME-
tried  `^[DELETE-ME-]` ,`^[DELETE-ME-*]` , but haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `grep -v`:

```
printf "%s\n" /home/shell/* | grep -v '/DELETE-ME-'
```

OR using find:

```
find /home/shell  -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "DELETE-ME-*"
```

Comment: your fix seems working, but how can i amend this in format of "/home/shell/??" as i need to pass this as input arguments of another script.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, but some reason i still am not able to use above both, as -f has to be path of single regex of string . 
./testscript.sh -f find /home/shell  -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "DELETE-ME-*" -s <ftp address> -u <username:pwd> -t <targetdirectory> -d <directory> -a <archive>

Comment: Suggest you to post code of `./testscript.sh` so that I suggest you better way out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `extglob`

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(DELETE-ME-*) # change echo to your actual command...
shopt -u extglob
```